# PyQt: accessing function and self outside of the class, from another function

Tags: python, pyqt, self-reference

Here's my problem:
I have created a gui using Qt Design and converted the *.ui to *.py and moved the code into my script.
I've got this so far, leaving out other function that aren't important for what I'm trying to do:

```py
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        MainWindow.resize(951, 487)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 261, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 951, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuAbout = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAbout.setObjectName("menuAbout")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionAbout = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbout.setObjectName("actionAbout")
        self.actionGitHub_Page = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionGitHub_Page.setObjectName("actionGitHub_Page")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menuAbout.addAction(self.actionAbout)
        self.menuAbout.addAction(self.actionGitHub_Page)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAbout.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.exit)
        self.actionGitHub_Page.triggered.connect(self.GitHub_link)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "GUI"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuAbout.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionAbout.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "About"))
        self.actionGitHub_Page.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GitHub Page"))

    def exit(self):
        sys.exit()

    def GitHub_link(self):
        os.system(
            "start \"\" https://github.com")

    def text(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)


class GUIThread(Thread):
    '''
    Provides a dedicated thread for the GUI
    '''

    def __init__(self, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        global Stopped
        try:
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
            MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
            MainWindow.show()

            # sys.exit(app.exec_())
            if(app.exec_() == 0):
                Stopped = True

        except:
            print("\n\nThe GUI thread raised an exception. Terminating...\n\n")
            Stopped = True

def main():
    global Stopped

    try:
        # Create a GUI thread to manage the visual stuff
        Gui_thread = GUIThread("GUI")
        Gui_thread.daemon = True
        Gui_thread.start()


        while(True):
            if Stopped == False:
                time.sleep(0.5)
            else:
                print("Closing...")
                sys.exit()

    # If any non-exit exception is raised then the specified thread will be closed
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("\n\nThe main thread raised an exception. Terminating...\n\n")
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Call main function and pass args given by user
    main()
```

Now I need a way to update the text of the label from anywhere in my code but I can't find a way to call the function

```
def text(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)
```

outside of the class.
For example, if I want to call it from the `def main()` I need to specify the "self" and "text" parameters but self is't defined in the main function.

My main goal is to being able to call the `def text(self, text)` function from pretty much anywhere in my script and update the label text.

I've tried to call it from the GUithread that I've created and do a while loop but this blocks the Qt thread and make the windows unusable and, at the end, terminate the code.
Is there anyone that can help me out with this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you running `QApplication` inside the thread? Can you not keep it out?

Comment: (little note: I've omitted other part of the entire codes that aren't related to the gui stuff). It's in a thread cause otherwise I can't call other stuff, since the gui loop starts when '''app.exec_()'''  is called; If I call other functions before that I need to return/end the loop of those before reaching '''app.exec_()''' and effectively "enter" the gui loop. If I don't use threads The gui will be stuck (******* is not responding on windows).

Comment: How about doing the other way round? Actually starting `app.exec_()` in main thread and then calling other threads separately?

Comment: I've already tried to do all the functions that I call in the run() function of the Gui thread directly in the main() but the problem is that when you call ```app.exec_()``` it waits for a return value from it. This is a problem since the following instructions are not executed until that "ends".

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
Ok.... so after some more tries I've found out that one of my previous tries actually works.

I just need to declare `ui = None` as a global variable (making it accessible from anywhere in the code) and the rest as the code in the question. But before I can actually use it I need to "give it time" to initialize all the gui stuff. The solution is pretty simple, put a simple `time.sleep(1)` after the Gui_thread declaration in the `main()` and from that the code works, I  can now have access to the `ui` object and it's functions and all other things.

Here's an example code for y'all:

```py
import time
import os, sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import threading
from threading import Thread

Stopped = False
ui = None

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        MainWindow.resize(951, 487)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 261, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 951, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuAbout = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAbout.setObjectName("menuAbout")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionAbout = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbout.setObjectName("actionAbout")
        self.actionGitHub_Page = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionGitHub_Page.setObjectName("actionGitHub_Page")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menuAbout.addAction(self.actionAbout)
        self.menuAbout.addAction(self.actionGitHub_Page)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAbout.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.exit)
        self.actionGitHub_Page.triggered.connect(self.GitHub_link)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "GUI"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuAbout.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionAbout.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "About"))
        self.actionGitHub_Page.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GitHub Page"))

    def exit(self):
        sys.exit()

    def GitHub_link(self):
        os.system(
            "start \"\" https://github.com")

    def text(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)


class GUIThread(Thread):
    '''
    Provides a dedicated thread for the GUI
    '''

    def __init__(self, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        global Stopped, ui
        try:
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
            MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
            MainWindow.show()

            # sys.exit(app.exec_())
            if(app.exec_() == 0):
                Stopped = True

        except:
            print("\n\nThe GUI thread raised an exception. Terminating...\n\n")
            Stopped = True

def main():
    global Stopped, ui

    try:
        # Create a GUI thread to manage the visual stuff
        Gui_thread = GUIThread("GUI")
        Gui_thread.daemon = True
        Gui_thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        ui.label.setText("Hello there")

        while(True):
            if Stopped == False:
                time.sleep(0.5)
            else:
                print("Closing...")
                sys.exit()

    # If any non-exit exception is raised then the specified thread will be closed
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("\n\nThe main thread raised an exception. Terminating...\n\n")
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Call main function and pass args given by user
    main()
```